# Replace / Remove String between two characters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I started to create a code (in VB.NET) to extract information from texts;
The thing that I could not find in StackOverflow and search engines is an example of replacing/removing the text between "<" and ">" 
Probably it is `REPLACE` or `REGEX`; I tried both, but could not figure it out;
Can I get some help....
Much appreciated...

```
 Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SSSS = Replace(Label1.Text, "<td>", vbNewLine, 1, , CompareMethod.Text)

    MessageBox.Show(SSSS)
End Sub
End Class
```

The above (in VB.NET)  will split my text into line if I have `<td>`; but I want to add the following: 
My Text I am working on is:
      `test1<img alt='dddddd' src='https://mekdam.com'><div class='what'>test2</div><div class='code'>more</div>`
I want to get `test1  test2` from that in VB.NET

Comment: Please post your code here. Also, are you trying to work with HTML here?

Comment: It is not html; it is vb.net as per my question and tags; No need to vote me down; if you know the answer, be positive and answer, if my question not clear, I can clarify it more; I will post the code shortly.

Comment: I did not vote down, and I was asking if you are trying to work with HTML since I would associate "<>" with HTML text. Now post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this

```
 Private Sub StrRep(ByVal xstr As String)

        Dim xst As Integer = xch.IndexOf("<")
        Dim xend As Integer = xch.IndexOf(">")

        Dim xsub As String = xstr .Substring(xst, (xend - xst) + 1)
        xstr = xstr .Replace(xsub, String.Empty)

        If xstr .Contains("<") Then
            Call StrRep(xstr )
        Else
            MsgBox(xstr )
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SATSON; Much appreciated; I tried your code, and am getting an error for the (xch) in the code? is it a typo; Please remember I am a beginner. Thanks again for help.

Comment: Thanks SATSON, now those errors gone, only (Call sdub) is the last error; seems the code is "Calling" a sub, that is missing? I think? Thanks again for help.

Comment: Change sdub to `StrRep`.