# Change Part of URL - Replace User with %USERNAME%

Tags: vb.net

I got a String which could be : C:\Users\info\Desktop\Folder in which case I want to replace the Part of the URL after \Users\ ..\ with **%Username%**.

So far I manage to replace the string when i know the part before the Username, in this case Users\ and the part after the Username. But i can't manage to define \ as the end because it thinks that Users \ is the end of string to replace.

So how can i change the dim SDelimEnd so it just gives back the Username

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub RadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton.Click
Dim sSource As String = txt1.text 'String that is being searched
Dim sDelimStart As String = "Users" 'First delimiting word
Dim sDelimEnd As String = "AppData" 'Second delimiting word
Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
    Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
    MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
        Strings.Replace(sSource,res,"\%username%\")
        MessageBox.Show(Strings.Replace(sSource,res,"\%username%\"))
        txt2.Text = Strings.Replace(sSource,res,"\%username%\")

Else
    MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: There is an official way in Win32 to get the profile directory path of a specified user - because users can have profile directories in different locations, or be using a roaming profile, or have a profile directory name that's different than their actual Windows username, and so on. Are you certain this is how you want to go about it - by doing a naive string-replacement?

Comment: Yes for the first. Or do you have a better work arround? :) Thank you for your answer

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198124/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-windows-special-folder-for-a-specific-user

Comment: `String.Contains` to check if string has **Users** inside it. Then `IndexOf("Users") + 6` to get everything after **Users\** and just replace

Comment: The Username could have any length

Comment: if its windows user yuo can retrieve it with: `Environment.UserName`

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\info\" + TextBox1.Text) = True Then
        Label1.Text = "Ok"
    Else
        Label1.Text = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your url with **myurl** and apply this code:

```
If myurl.contains("Users") Then
    myurl = myurl.Replace("info\Desktop\Folder", "%Username%")
End If
```

If **myurl** can be longer path (or different than *info\Desktop\Folder*, eg: *info\Desktop\Folder\hello\wazapp*) then:

```
If myurl.contains("Users") Then
    Dim cut_at As String = "\Users\"
    Dim stringSeparators() As String = {cut_at}
    Dim split = original.Split(stringSeparators, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    myurl = myurl.replace(split(1), "")
End If
```

Comment: will this also work when the username is for example Daniel or ABC92ue2u?

Comment: Yes­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: I tried this code it doesnt work :/
Is there an option where you can just replace a word after /user/ and before the next /

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566393/replace-remove-string-between-two-characters

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution but I can not define Users\ as Start and \ as end.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub RadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton.Click
Dim sSource As String = txt1.text 'String that is being searched
Dim sDelimStart As String = "Users" 'First delimiting word
Dim sDelimEnd As String = "AppData" 'Second delimiting word
Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
    Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
    MessageBox.Show(res) 'Display
        Strings.Replace(sSource,res,"\%username%\")
        MessageBox.Show(Strings.Replace(sSource,res,"\%username%\"))


Else
    MessageBox.Show("One or both of the delimiting words were not found!")
End If

End Sub
```

End Class